# Converting Fixnum to Array in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to convert a fixnum to an array in ruby?

For Example:

```
 
s = SituationType.all(:conditions => {:name => 'did not match retrieved design - text misspelled'}).collect(&:id)
result: [10034, 10055]
```

sf = situation_type_id = SituationType.find_by_name('did not match retrieved design - text misspelled').id
result: 10034

s -sf says, 
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following

```
s - [sf]
```

Since sf is an integer, It cannot do the subtraction unless you convert it into an array